# Gnome panel and terminal not working on VNC

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, vnc, amazon-ec2

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 instance on AWS EC2. I've installed vnc4server, ubuntu desktop and gnome panel to remote GUI.

The first time I connected everything was Ok but after I restarted my instance, the gnome elements didn't start (there is no top bar and I can't open a gnome terminal).

This is my xstartup config:

```
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

And my log has this otuput:

```
Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb 25 2015 23:02:21
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc


Mon Jul 16 01:21:25 2018
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!

** (gnome-settings-daemon:3369): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=ec972c0eaa654f86885a404d2922ddf7 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1

** (gnome-panel:3368): WARNING **: Failed to get session bus: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=ec972c0eaa654f86885a404d2922ddf7 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
Window manager warning: Log level 32: could not find XKB extension.
Window manager warning: Missing composite extension required for compositing

(nautilus:3371): libunity-CRITICAL **: file unity-launcher.c: line 1502: unexpected error: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=ec972c0eaa654f86885a404d2922ddf7 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1 (g-spawn-exit-error-quark, 1)

(nautilus:3371): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity_launcher_entry_dbus_impl_construct: assertion 'conn != NULL' failed

(nautilus:3371): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-inspector.vala:96: Unable to connect to session bus: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=ec972c0eaa654f86885a404d2922ddf7 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1

(nautilus:3371): libunity-CRITICAL **: file unity-launcher.c: line 1502: unexpected error: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=ec972c0eaa654f86885a404d2922ddf7 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1 (g-spawn-exit-error-quark, 1)

(nautilus:3371): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity_launcher_entry_dbus_impl_construct: assertion 'conn != NULL' failed

(nautilus:3371): libunity-CRITICAL **: file unity-launcher.c: line 1502: unexpected error: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=ec972c0eaa654f86885a404d2922ddf7 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1 (g-spawn-exit-error-quark, 1)

(nautilus:3371): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity_launcher_entry_dbus_impl_construct: assertion 'conn != NULL' failed

Mon Jul 16 01:33:37 2018
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::59176
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8

Mon Jul 16 01:33:38 2018
 SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)

Mon Jul 16 01:33:41 2018
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565

Mon Jul 16 01:33:42 2018
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 6 (8bpp) rgb222
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=ec972c0eaa654f86885a404d2922ddf7 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
```